# How to repeat a key value for every column in a fixed length file

Tags: unix, text, awk, sed, flat-file

I have to repeat the key value after every 14 characters in a line

My file looks like this :

```
KEYVALUE1 201604141111I201604141111C201604141111D201604141111E201604141111F  
KEYVALUE1 201604141111G  
KEYVALUE2 201604141111I201604141111C201604141111D201604141111E201604141111F  
KEYVALUE2 201604141111G201604141111F  
KEYVALUE3 201604141111I  
KEYVALUE4 201604141111G201604141111I
```

My output should look like this,

```
KEYVALUE1 201604141111I  
KEYVALUE1 201604141111C  
KEYVALUE1 201604141111D  
KEYVALUE1 201604141111F  
KEYVALUE1 201604141111G  
KEYVALUE2 201604141111I  
KEYVALUE2 201604141111C  
KEYVALUE2 201604141111D  
KEYVALUE2 201604141111F  
KEYVALUE2 201604141111G  
KEYVALUE2 201604141111F  
KEYVALUE3 201604141111I  
KEYVALUE4 201604141111G  
KEYVALUE4 201604141111I
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk for simplicity, clarity, robustness, portability, efficiency, and most other desirable qualities of software:

```
$ awk '{ while ($2!="") { print $1, substr($2,1,13); $2=substr($2,14) } }' file
KEYVALUE1 201604141111I
KEYVALUE1 201604141111C
KEYVALUE1 201604141111D
KEYVALUE1 201604141111E
KEYVALUE1 201604141111F
KEYVALUE1 201604141111G
KEYVALUE2 201604141111I
KEYVALUE2 201604141111C
KEYVALUE2 201604141111D
KEYVALUE2 201604141111E
KEYVALUE2 201604141111F
KEYVALUE2 201604141111G
KEYVALUE2 201604141111F
KEYVALUE3 201604141111I
KEYVALUE4 201604141111G
KEYVALUE4 201604141111I
```

Comment: Thanks ED .. This works like a gem :) I just made a minor edit with the positions . its 14 characters instead of 13. Post the change my command looks like : awk '{ while ($2!="") { print $1, substr($2,1,14); $2=substr($2,15) } }' $FILE_NAME > BREAK_FILE

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to perl:

```
perl -lane 'print "$F[0] $_" for $F[1] =~/.{13}/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^\([^ ]* \)\(.\{13\}\)/{s/^\([^ ]* \)\(.\{13\}\)/&\n\1/g;P;D;}' file
```

Comment: This works fine, But if i have data like KEYVALUE2 201604141111G201604141111F then i get lines with only keyvalue and blanks which is not intended.But still a great alternative :) I am a SED FAN too :)

Answer (score 0):

Or this one:

```
sed '{
  :j
  /^[^ ]* .\{13\}.\{13\}/ {
    h
    s/^\([^ ]*\) \(.\{13\}\)\(.*\)$/\1 \2/
    p
    x
    s/^\([^ ]*\) \(.\{13\}\)\(.*\)$/\1 \3/
    h
    b j
  }
}' file
```